Vocabulary sizes of Latin authors in terms of lexemes
I would like to know the size of the vocabulary of various Latin authors. For example, Andreas Willi (in: Colloquial and Literary Latin, Eleanor Dickey & Anna Chahoud (eds), ch13, p229) mentions "Caesar's linguistic self-discipline, which famously
restricts the vocabulary of the Bellum Gallicum to less than 1,300 lexemes".
We can measure an author's published vocabulary by counting the number of lexemes (excluding names) occurring in all of their known published works. Here are two useful definitions:

lexeme: abstract word, equivalent to the content of one lexical entry in a dictionary
lemma: one inflected form of a lexeme, chosen by social or editorial convention to be used as the headword in a dictionary to represent a lexeme there for the purpose of indexing

Knowing the size of an author's vocabulary can serve as a useful metric when evaluating the difficulty of understanding an author's writings. Needless to say, it would be foolish to use it as the sole metric to evaluate an author's works:

syntactic complexity is in principle independent of an author's vocabulary size
the difficulty of a piece of writing will depend heavily on the subject matter and internal logic
authors don't have uniform difficulty; we know that Cicero's letters make for easier reading than some of his other works

How many words would one need to have studied at a minimum to read certain authors without a dictionary? I'm particularly interested in: Caesar (incl Bellum Civile), Cicero, Tacitus, Virgil (esp his Aeneid). However, that would be 4-5 separate questions.
Hence, for the purpose of this post, let's consider a specific question about sources or tools: Where can one easily look up the number of lexemes (ideally excluding names) used by a certain Latin author?

Note: I noticed that the tag vocabulary is likely not a good fit, given its description in the tag wiki. However, I am not sure what other tags to use; hence please feel free to liberally edit my list of tags.

Related question here.

By the way, if anyone knows the answer for any of {Cicero, Tacitus, Virgil, Virgil in the Aeneid}, let me know, and I'll create separate questions for these, for you to post your answer thereunder.

Unfortunately I don't know of a reference to look this up. Would you be interested in a way to calculate it yourself?

@Draconis Yes, absolutely. Python works well for me.

I tentatively switched vocabulary to research, but I'm open to pondering alternatives still.

You'll have to do some cleaning, but you could also go chapter by chapter in Perseus' vocabulary tool.
As an example, here's Caesar's Gallic War 1.1's vocabulary.

ad    6   6   6   6   0.0073  to, toward  Lewis & Short, Elem. Lewis
flumen  6   6   6   12  0.0341  a flowing, flood, stream, running water     Lewis & Short, Elem. Lewis
et  5   5   5   17  0.0014  and     Lewis & Short, Elem. Lewis
Belgae  6   4   4.5     21.5    0.1715  the Belgians    Lewis & Short
ab  19  3   4   25.5    0.027   all the way from    Lewis & Short
finis   4   4   4   29.5    0.0196  that which divides, a boundary, limit, border   Lewis & Short, Elem. Lewis
pars    4   4   4   33.5    0.0142  a part, piece, portion, share, division, section    Lewis & Short, Elem. Lewis
is  11  1   3.5     37  0.0385  he, she, it, the one mentioned  Lewis & Short, Elem. Lewis
sum     8   2   3.5     40.5    0.0029  to be, exist, live  Lewis & Short, Elem. Lewis
10  qui     39  0   3.11    43.61   0.0142  who? which? what? what kind of a?   Lewis & Short, Elem. Lewis
qui     39  0   3.11    46.72   0.0123  in what manner? how? whereby? by what means? why?   Lewis & Short, Elem. Lewis
Rhenus  3   3   3   49.72   0.0511  The Rhine   Lewis & Short
septentriones   3   3   3   52.72   0.0814  the Great Bear  Lewis & Short
omnis   3   3   3   55.72   0.0043  all, every  Lewis & Short, Elem. Lewis
Garumna     3   3   3   58.72   0.1009  a river of Gaul     Lewis & Short
pertineo    3   3   3   61.72   0.0513  to stretch out, reach, extend   Lewis & Short, Elem. Lewis
incolo  2   2   2   63.72   0.0297  to be at home, abide, dwell     Lewis & Short, Elem. Lewis
Oceanus     2   2   2   65.72   0.0231  the great sea, outer sea, ocean     Lewis & Short, Elem. Lewis
gero    2   2   2   67.72   0.0084  to bear about, bear, carry, wear, have, hold, sustain   Lewis & Short, Elem. Lewis
20  lingua  2   2   2   69.72   0.013   the tongue  Lewis & Short, Elem. Lewis

Then, you can go in and delete the part of the URL that has the chapter information, in this case chapter%3D1, and you'll get all the words from the first book, like this:

a     240     0   15  824.24  0.673   from, away from, out of     Lewis & Short, Elem. Lewis
a   240     0   15  839.24  0.673   [unavailable]   Lewis & Short
ab  285     45  60  899.24  0.4066  all the way from    Lewis & Short
abditus     2   0   0.5     899.74  0.0206  hidden, concealed, secret   Lewis & Short, Elem. Lewis
abdo    3   1   1.5     901.24  0.0268  to put away, remove, set aside  Lewis & Short, Elem. Lewis
abduco  1   1   1   902.24  0.0177  to lead away, take away, carry off, remove, lead aside:     Lewis & Short, Elem. Lewis
abstineo    1   1   1   903.24  0.0153  to keep back, keep off, hold back   Lewis & Short, Elem. Lewis
190     absum   9   9   9   912.24  0.0764  abesse, in general, to be away from, be absent:     Lewis & Short, Elem. Lewis
accedo  4   4   4   916.24  0.037   to go to, come to, come near, draw near, approach, enter:   Lewis & Short, Elem. Lewis
accepta     7   0   0.58    916.83  0.1051  a portion of land granted to an individual by the state     Lewis & Short
accepto     7   0   0.58    917.41  0.1045  to take, receive    Lewis & Short, Elem. Lewis
acceptum    10  0   0.92    918.33  0.134   the receipt     Lewis & Short, Elem. Lewis
accido  14  0   3.5     921.83  0.1718  to fall upon, fall to, reach by falling     Lewis & Short, Elem. Lewis
accido  14  0   3.5     925.33  0.1735  to cut, cut at, cut into, cut down, fell    Lewis & Short, Elem. Lewis

You'll need to do some cleaning up, but that shouldn't take so long if you know a little bit of code.

Unfortunately, I don't know any source which lists this information. But, it's not too hard to estimate it for yourself!
First, get the relevant authors' work in some plain text format. The PHI corpus is a great resource for this, though the modern web version doesn't let you download it all as text files any more (or, I don't know how to). But it's not too hard to get your hands on one of the earlier editions that was distributed on CD-ROMs. CLTK will then let you iterate over these files in various useful ways.
Then, iterate over the words, and run them through Morpheus, CLTK's lemmatizer, or the like to convert them to lemmata. Count how many times each lemma appears, and the number of distinct lemmata. And see what you find!
